# Login users with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We're in the process of creating a solution where we want to create user accounts. We do not want to manage the passwords ourselves due to the security aspect. We've been looking at Azure AD as our identity provider.

From the documentation, we can create users, change passwords and so on using their api documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

However we cannot find any way to authenticate users, as the api does not expose any login endpoints.

Is it possible to log a user in with Azure AD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to log a user in with Azure AD?

It is certainly possible to log a user in with Azure AD. You will need to create an application in your Azure AD (also called a Service Principal) and use that to authenticate a user. You can find more information and examples about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview.